# How to map JSON to C# when Json Key starts with a number/digit RestSharp

Tags: c#, json, facebook-graph-api, restsharp

I am using RestSharp to consume facebook graph api. Facebook decided it is smart to start out names with numbers, which makes mapping difficult.
Here is a snippet of returned data:

```
 "actions": [
        {
          "action_type": "offsite_conversion.custom.1033557723384764",
          "value": 1087,
          "1d_view": 18,
          "28d_click": 1069
        },
```

I just tried this:

```
class Action
{
    public string action_type { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }

    [DeserializeAs(Name = "1d_view")]
    public float _1d_view { get; set; }
    [DeserializeAs(Name = "28d_click")]
    public float _28d_click { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit**
So those are floats I had ints
[image]

How can I map the two fields that start with digits? C# won't allow me to start a variable name with a number obviously, so what can I do?

**Solved:** I was getting correct information. `The [DeserializeAs(Name = "28d_click")]` solved it for me.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  `new JsonDeserializer().Deserialize<RootObject>(response)` seems to work correctly and honors the `[DeserializeAs(Name = "1d_view")]` attribute.  Note you've got an error in the second attribute, it should be `[DeserializeAs(Name = "28d_click")]`

Comment: @dbc I got it figured out! Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: I was getting correct information. The `[DeserializeAs(Name = "28d_click")]` solved it for me.